# Close the service when remove the app via swipe in android

Tags: android, android-service

I want to close the service when user removes the app from current running app list. Here, what I'm doing, when user starts the app, service gets started and remain in progress. But when user removes the app via swipe, new service is being created. I want to close the service. Below is my code.

```
// Start service using AlarmManager



    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);

    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                5000, pintent);
    startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
```

### MyService.java

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service {
    int count = 0;
    public MyService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "The new Service was Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // For time consuming an long tasks you can launch a new thread here...
        count++;
        Toast.makeText(this, " Service Started" + "  " + count, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }



}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According with  google's employee Dianne Hackborn explains in  a comment on one of her [Google+ posts](https://plus.google.com/105051985738280261832/posts/GfwRYCC42uX), you have to implemente the onTaskremoved on your service.

> [W]hat specifically happens when you swipe away a recent task is it:
>   (1) kills any background or empty processes of the application (see
>   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle
>   for what this means), and (2) uses the new
>   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onTaskRemoved(android.content.Intent)
>   API to tell any services of the application about the task being
>   removed so it can do whatever it thinks is appropriate.

So I think you can do it this way: In that callback you have to stop the service, and tell the alarm manager to stop starting it again. For that, first of all, you need to pass to the service the pending intent that you use with the AlarmManger, so the service can use the intent to cancel the schedule. 
At least, you need all this:

In your service

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private DefaultBinder mBinder;
    private AlarmManager  alarmManager ;
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

    private void setAlarmIntent(PendingIntent alarmIntent){
        this.alarmIntent=alarmIntent;
    }

    public void onCreate() {
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        mBinder = new DefaultBinder(this);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public void onTaskRemoved (Intent rootIntent){
        alarmManager.cancel(alarmIntent);
        this.stopSelf();
    }
}
```

Then in other file, you create DefaultBinder Class

```
public class DefaultBinder extends Binder {
    MyService s;

    public DefaultBinder( MyService s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    public MyService getService() {
        return s;
    }
}
```

in your activity

```
MyService service;
protected ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {
        service = ((DefaultBinder) binder).getService();
        service.setAlarmIntent(pIntent);
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        service = null;
    }
};

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    bindService(new Intent(this, MainService.class), mConnection,
            Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if (mConnection != null) {
        try {
            unbindService(mConnection);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: hey thanks... It's working... But when I go to home screen, service stops, and when I restart my app, service starts... I don't want it... What I want here is, service should running until I remove from app list... how can I do that???

Comment: instead of doing it on the onStop callback, you can do it onDestroy().

onStop is called when the activity is not visible, and onDestroy is called when activity is not any longer in memory. Anyways, in android this is not trustable, since the system can destroy an activity without calling onDestroy, or can consider to keep it running in background even if you close it in the app list.

Comment: let me edit the answer so it is more usefull to you.

Comment: ya i tried with onDestroy, but what is happening in this case, service stops, but I want it to be continued until user removes from the current list of apps...

Comment: in that situation, the system calls onTaskRemoved (Intent rootIntent) of the service. so, just implement it as in the updated example

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42557/discussion-between-carlos-robles-and-anil-bhatiya)

Comment: onTaskRemoved does not get called when the app gets killed by the system (low memory conditions etc). In that case, the service will never know when to stop itself. How do you suggest we deal with that case?